# Python pre-order to postfix notation reverse polish notation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-tree

I am trying to find a solution in Python to try and move the pre-order notation e.g."* + 7 3 - 2 9" or "+ 55 26" to post notation or the reverse polish notation. the expected result would be e.g. "7 3 + 2 9 - *" and "55 26 +" respectively. I did some research on the binary trees however with the math functions I am struggling. What I have currently is the following:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data
```

## Function to check for operators

```
def isOperator(self, c):
    return c == '+' or c == '-' or c == '*' or c == '/'
```

## Insert Node

```
def insert(self, data):

    if self.data:
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
    else:
        self.data = data
```

## Print the Tree

```
def PrintTree(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.PrintTree()
    print( self.data),
    if self.right:
        self.right.PrintTree()
```

## Preorder traversal

## Root -> Left ->Right

```
def PreorderTraversal(self, root):
    res = []
    if root:
        res.append(root.data)
        res = res + self.PreorderTraversal(root.left)
        res = res + self.PreorderTraversal(root.right)
    return res
```

## Postorder traversal

## Left ->Right -> Root

```
def PostorderTraversal(self, root):
    res = []
    if root:
        res = self.PostorderTraversal(root.left)
        res = res + self.PostorderTraversal(root.right)
        res.append(root.data)
    return res
```

Any assistance in getting this code complete will be highly appreciated, as I am not able to figure this out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you just have the `Node` class, and are all these methods of the `Node` class? Instead of posting little snippets of code, it is better to have one code block, so we can see the exact context, and derive what `self` is (for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some issues:

- Your `insert` method applies *binary search tree* logic, which is not relevant for the expression tree you want to build. Instead it should keep track of the insertion spot for any next data.
- It is not clear whether these are all methods of the `Node` class, but at least `isOperator` is unrelated to any instance values, so it should not be a method (with `self` argument), but either a stand alone function or a static method. Moreover, if the input is valid, then an operator is anything that is not a number.
- Methods should not print (except for debugging purposes): leave that for the main driver code to do. Methods can help printing by returning an iterator, or a representation (implementing `__repr__`).
- It is common practice to not use an initial capital letter for function names and reserve that for class names.
- I would suggest a separate class for the tree. This will be handy to track where the next node should be inserted, using a path (stack).

Here is how you could implement it:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):  # default iteration is inorder
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.data
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right

    def preorder(self):
        yield self.data
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.preorder()
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.preorder()

    def postorder(self):
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.postorder()
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.postorder()
        yield self.data


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.path = []

    def insert(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            node = self.root = Node(data)
        elif not self.path:
            raise ValueError("Cannot add more nodes")
        elif self.path[-1].left:
            node = self.path[-1].right = Node(data)
        else:
            node = self.path[-1].left = Node(data)
        if not data.isnumeric(): # internal node
            self.path.append(node)
        else:
            while self.path and self.path[-1].right:
                self.path.pop()
            
    @staticmethod
    def fromstr(s):
        tree = Tree()
        for token in s.split():
            tree.insert(token)
        return tree

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root

    def preorder(self):
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root.preorder()

    def postorder(self):
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root.postorder()
```

Here is how you can run it:

```
def postorder(s):
    tree = Tree.fromstr(s)
    # Just for debugging, print the tree in inorder:
    print(*tree)  # this calls `__iter__`
    return " ".join(tree.postorder())

print(postorder("* + 7 3 - 2 9"))
```

Output (inorder and postorder):

```
7 + 3 * 2 - 9
7 3 + 2 9 - *
```

Comment: Hi trincot, thank you very much for the elaboration and highlighting how to put this all together. It is truly appreciated, I have been struggling for weeks to try and get this correct. Thank you

Comment: Last question, how would I be able to run the class like this: postorder("* + 7 3 - 2 9")?

Comment: Then what would be the instance of the class? Why would you then need a class?

Comment: I updated my answer... Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi trincot, apologies for the delay in my response. Is it possible to have the:

def postorder(s):
    tree = Tree.fromstr(s)
    # Just for debugging, print the tree in inorder:
    print(*tree)  # this calls `__iter__`
    return " ".join(tree.postorder())

inside of the code and only send:
postorder("* + 7 3 - 2 9")

to get:
7 3 + 2 9 - *

as an output?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Apologies, I will try to elaborate. Is it possible to send  postorder(" + 7 3 - 2 9") to run the code and get an out put of 7 3 + 2 9 - *

Comment: That's what it is doing now, right? Not sure what you mean with "send" though. Do you mean print? Surely you have all elements to print where you want. The result is there. Don't really understand what the problem is? Could you at least mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: You are 100% correct, I figured it out it works as expected. Sorry my mistake, I am still very new to python. Thank you trincot